# How can I retrieve the href element from a button in a casperJS script?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

```
casper.then(function() {
this.test.assertExists({
    type: 'xpath',
    path: '//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]'
}, "Found Multiviewer button");
```

});

The above button is found but I cannot access the href element by doing:

```
var element = x('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]');

console.log('element'+this.getElementAttribute(element,'href'));
```

results in:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.getElementAttribute(element,'href')')
```

I have also tried:

```
this.getElementAttribute('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]','href')')
```

casperJS version is 1.1.0-beta3 (OSX 10.8.5)

Once I've retrieved the URL I then need to open it...

```
var baseTargetUrl;
casper.then(function() {
    var element = x('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]');
    console.log('url is: '+this.getElementAttribute(element,'href'));
    baseTargetUrl = this.getElementAttribute(element,'href');
});

casper.thenOpen(baseTargetUrl, function() {
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});
```

Error:

```
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')
#           TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')
#               at cleanUrl (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/utils.js:112)
#               at open (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1405)
#               at _step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1832)
#               at runStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553)
#               at checkStep (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399)
#    stack: not provided
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')          
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/utils.js:112 in cleanUrl
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1405 in open
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1832 in _step
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553 in runStep
  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399 in checkStep
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')
#    type: error
#    subject: false
#    error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'url.toLowerCase')"
#    stack: in cleanUrl() in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/utils.js:112
in open() in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1405
in _step() in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1832
in runStep() in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:1553
in checkStep() in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/casperjs/modules/casper.js:399
```

How should I pass the URL to the next function?

Comment: Please remove the second part of the question, since you already have a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20932947/1816580) specifically for this. You can also fix the indentation for the first snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you are trying to reference casper with `this`, but you aren't wrapping it in a casper function.

```
casper.then(function() {
    var element = x('//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/a[2]');
    console.log('element'+this.getElementAttribute(element,'href'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The top snippet worked (the second one doesn't).

Comment: Ok, I'll take that one out.

Comment: thanks. I also need to then pass the URL to casper.thenOpen(). Whats the correct way to do that?